# Where can I find completed img's pack for training opencv face recognizing system?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

So...
Where can I find completed img's pack for training opencv face recognizing system?
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look [here](http://www.face-rec.org/databases/)

the [att faces db](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/Research/DTG/attarchive/pub/data/att_faces.tar.Z) was probably used a lot  ( if you look at the docs. )

once you downloaded a set of images, you'll want to run the [little python script](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#appendix) to generate the needed csv file for training

if you opt for the yale db, you'll have to convert the images to png or pgm first ( opencv can't handle gif's)

but honestly, in the end you want to use a db, that consists entirely of *faces you want to recognize* [that is, your own db].

unlike most ml algo's it does not need explicit 'negative' images[people other than you want to recognize] here. thoose only add noise and degrade the actual recognition.

the only situation, where you'd want that is when there's only 1 person to recognize. you#d need some others there to increase 'contrast'